# does $1$ belong to $\{1+(1/m): m =1, 2,\cdots \}$?

Tags: real-analysis

This is from apostol's analysis chapter $3$ exercise $2(f)$.

It is about finding the accumulation points of $(-1)^n + 1/m$, where $m$ and $n$ are starting from $1, 2,...$

I am a bit confused whether $1$ belongs to the set 
$$\{1+(1/m): m=1, 2, \cdots\}$$

If $1$ belongs to it, then it will be the accumulation point,
if not, then it won't.

Answer (score 1):

No. The notation that $m$ ranges from $1$ to $\infty$ means that $m$ is any number greater than one, but it must be a number; the notation does not tell you to "plug $\infty$ in for $m$". Therefore, $1$ does not belong to this set (indeed, everything in this set is greater than $1$).

However, your definition of accumulation point is not correct, so you should review it. It turns out that $1$ is an accumulation point of this set.

Comment: Oh! I made a mistake. Thank you! Now I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I think an accumulation point does not have to belong to the set.
So with this definition, both 1 and -1 would be accumulation points.

Comment: Yeah... I was not aware of it. Thanks!